# Issue with script using AD PSDrive in Windows Powershell on Windows 11 22H2

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm on a Windows 11 22H2 machine and I'm trying to write a script to gain some ACL information for objects in AD and am running into issues across OSes that I don't understand.

Most documentation references using the AD PS Drive.  When using Win11+WinPosh it pukes when my DN has an escaped comma (e.g., 'lastname, firstname').  It complains that:

```
Get-Acl : The object name has bad syntax
```

This works fine in Windows Server 2016+WinPosh.  I wonder why that is?? I tried Posh7 and it works Win11 but not Win2016 due to an older ActiveDirectory module (v1.0.0.0 vs v1.0.1.0).

An alternative I found was to not use the AD PSDrive at all, and instead specify the full namespace, such as:

```
Get-ACL -Path "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll/ActiveDirectory:://RootDSE/$dn"
```

Even this behaves differently across each OS! Works in Win11+WinPosh, but not Win2016+WinPosh nor Win11+Posh7.  It complains:

```
Cannot find a provider with the name 
 Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll\ActiveDirectory'.
```

If I drop the '.dll' and use:

```
Get-Acl -Path "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management\ActiveDirectory:://RootDSE/$dn"
```

It now works for Win2016+WinPosh and Win11+Posh7, but NOT Win11+WinPosh! In this case, it complains:

```
Cannot find a provider with the name 
 Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management\ActiveDirectory'.
```

What is going on here???  Why is Win2016+WinPosh working more like Win11+Posh7 than Win11+Winposh??  I'd expect WinPosh 5.1 to work the same across each OS. Ultimately why is this even a problem in Win11 at all? Is there anywhere I can report what seems to be a bug?